# Unwind Segue skips UITabBarController to previous UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I’m experiencing a problem where an Unwind Segue is skipping a UITabBarController and going to the previous UIViewController instead. My current set up is

UINavController > UIViewController1 > UIViewController2 > UITabBarController(UIViewController3) > UIViewController4

When I use my Unwind segue from UIViewController4, I’m returned to UIViewController2, rather than my UITabBarController(UIViewController3).

As a test I have entered the following code

```
-(IBAction)doneUnWindSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Anything? 1");
}
```

in UIViewControllers 1 and 2 and also in UIViewController3 inside my UITabBarController. (The number after "Anything?" is changed for each view controller so I know which one is called.)

When the code is removed from UIViewController2, the Unwind Segue goes to UIViewController1 and when removed from both 1 and 2, nothing happens. I can’t see any way to get it to unwind to UIViewController3.

[image]

When clicking on the right arrow next to the action, I am taken to the correct place in UIViewController3 inside the UITabBarController. (Assuming that the code above has been removed from UIViewController 1 and 2. Clicking that arrow while it is not while take me to UIViewController2, then UIViewController1 if it has been removed from UIViewController2)

I’m calling my Unwind when tapping on a UITableViewCell in UIViewController4, but I’ve gotten the same results from a UIButton located within that same ViewController. When creating the Unwind Segue, I drag from a Prototype cell to the Exit icon and choose "Selection Segue" with the relevant action.

Hopefully I've explained this fully as it is a little complex and a very strange issue.

Thank you for any help you can provide.